# Which tools to use to record screen for a presentation?

Tags: flash, demo

I have a presentation in the next few days , it's for my final year project in computer engineering...

I have to show a demo of my work , so I'm wondering what will be the best tool to use to record the demo from my computer (with autozooming etc) , and also for flash , I want to have a good presentation with flash , what can I use ?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

A quick way is to use the record software, recommand the Camtasia, which was simple, easy to use.

Comment: Camtasia is the best screen capture software I've used so far on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Camtasia is very popular, but there are many other solutions are available in the market today, like [PresentationTube](http://presentationtube.com/), [Prezi](http://prezi.com/) and [PowToon](http://www.powtoon.com/).
[PresentationTube](http://presentationtube.com/), for example, offers a video presentation recorder and video sharing platform to help presenters record and share quality video presentations in a new way. The video presentation recorder allows presenters to narrate and annotate PowerPoint slides and synchronize a variety of essential visual aids, including webcam streaming, whiteboard, drawing board, web browser content, and desktop recording.